# Adding extra field on Main menu, similar to Amazon.com

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I'm building a new website on Drupal 7 and my client wants a menu that in addition to the menu items he be able to add html content, very similar to Amazon.com menu. Should I create a content type for my menu instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use the [TB mega menu module](https://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) add your html content to a block and add the block to the menu

> TB Mega Menu is developed following Drupal standards and best
>   practices. Along with those must-have functions of a mega menu:
>   display not just menu items but image, slideshow, video, article and
>   customize any of them upon your favour...

Answer (score 0):

This module will help a lot for your requirements https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_descriptions